# Meaning of this sentence: 我几个月后再来

Tags: time

I just want to know the exact meaning of this sentence:

> 我几个月后再来

I have some options:

1. A few months later I come again
2. Next month I come again
3. Other meaning

Thanks

Comment: 1✓(months),next month is 下月

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will come again after a few months:
"I" "a few months" "after" "again come."

Answer (score 0):

I will return in a few months. 
Or as you said
I will come again after a few months.